# Is it possible to write a Java printf statement that prints the statement itself?

Tags: java, printf, quine

Is it possible to have a Java `printf` statement, whose output is the statement itself?

Some snippet to illustrate:

```
// attempt #1
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.printf("something");

}
}
```

This prints `something`.

So the output of attempt #1 is not quite exactly the `printf` statement in attempt #1. We can try something like this:

```
// attempt #2
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.printf("System.out.printf(\"something\");");

}
}
```

And now the output is `System.out.printf("something");`

So now the output of attempt #2 matches the statement in output #1, but we're back to the problem we had before, since we need the output of attempt #2 to match the statement in attempt #2.

So is it possible to write a one-line `printf` statement that prints itself?

Comment: This is a variant on the more general notion of a [quine](http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/quine.htm).

Comment: @ire_and_curses: yes, which is why I tagged it as such. The main difference is the requirement for a one-liner `printf`, so you can't store anything in an explicit local variable.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your tag there.

Answer (score 6):

It's not pretty, but this is certainly possible:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.out.printf("System.out.printf(%c%s%1$c,34,%1$c%2$s%1$c);",34,"System.out.printf(%c%s%1$c,34,%1$c%2$s%1$c);");

}
}
```

The output ([as run on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/dpHK2)) is:

```
System.out.printf("System.out.printf(%c%s%1$c,34,%1$c%2$s%1$c);",34,"System.out.printf(%c%s%1$c,34,%1$c%2$s%1$c);");
```

This output matches the `printf` statement.

There are likely to be shorter solutions.

#### See also

- [`java.util.Formatter` syntax](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

  - `%[argument_index$]conversion`

Answer (score 2):

System.out is a static PrintStream instance which may be replaced with any PrintStream by inovking System.out.setOut(PrintStream s).
So, just write a subclass of PrintStream and override the necessary methods.
The following is just a very simple example for demonstration. It's advisable to override more methods.

```
    public class VerbosePrintStream extends PrintStream{

        public VerbosePrintStream (PrintStream ps){
            super(ps, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void println(String x) {
            super.println("System.out.println(\""+x + "\");");
        }

    }
```

Now we test the above class:

```
VerbosePrintStream vps = new VerbosePrintStream(System.out);
    System.setOut(vps);
    System.out.println("test string");
```

Comment: Interesting, but the idea is to use the bare bone code skeleton above, no declaration whatsoever, local variable or type, no other statements, just write the `printf` statement however you want that satisfies the above condition.